# How to force TextMergeViewer to flush content even if content is unchanged?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I am implementing an editor that works on a distant document. The document is first downloaded, copied in a local cached file, displayed to the user who edits and saves it. On the 'save' action, the document is uploaded back to the server. Classic.

But sometimes, if the distant document has been modified by another user during the download/edit/upload cycle, a conflict is detected and a compare editor is presented to the user : the local version is displayed on the left pane (and editable) and the distant on the right pane (and read-only). The user does the "merge" operation manually (I don't consider automatic merge yet) and when the save action is launched, the comparison result overwrites the localy cached file that is afterwards uploaded onto the server. This is still a classic issue.

The problem is: if the user wants to discard the distant modifications, and thus wants to save the document as is without modifying the left pane, the compare editor refuses to flush the content of the pane in the local file and I can not detect that the user launched the save action to init the upload operation. Why the compare editor refuses to overwrite the local version is quite simple: since no modification has been made, it considers that there is nothing to flush.

I am trying to find a way to make it believe something has changed, but It seems that the TextMergeViewer that handles the comparison is not listening to any model change, and is so far from my code, that I don't know how to reach it (and it seems that I could not set the left pane as dirty anyway).

Comment: How are you creating the compare editor?

Comment: I am doing:

`MyComparatorInput compInput = new MyComparatorInput(...);
CompareUI.openCompareEditor(compInput);`

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am setting the _CompareEditorInput_ (mentionned earlier as "_MyComparatorInput_") dirty with `setLeftDirty(true)`